# Range define not working

Tags: excel, vba

I receive the error "application defined or object defined error" when running the below code:

```
Sub FillRowst()
     Dim LR As Integer
      LR = Range("M" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LR, T), Cells(LR + 1, T)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

It is working fine with following code

```
Sub FillRowsu()
     Dim LR As Integer
      LR = Range("M" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & LR + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: Put quotes around the `T`s in your Cells.  So `Range(Cells(LR, "T"), Cells(LR + 1, "T"))`

Comment: -or use the column number instead of the letter

Comment: You may also want to consider using the `Long` data type instead of `Integer` for your `LR` row counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you say this:

```
Cells(LR + 1, T)
```

It thinks that T is a variable just like LR is. Since you want it to literally be "T" you need to put it in quotation marks or assign it to a variable and use that. So either:

```
Cells(LR+1, "T")
```

Or

```
dim col as string
col = "T"
Cells(LR+1, col)
```